# Get all Custom Option

Tags: custom-options

i need get all Custom Option in magento, get radiobutton, checkbox, textarea and etc..

Let me know how i can do this for my product template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get custom option collection:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection()
    ->addTitleToResult($storeId)
    ->addPriceToResult($storeId)
    ->addValuesToResult($storeId)
```

All the date you need is in the tables:

```
catalog_product_option*
```

**Update**:

To get option html, take a look into

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options::getOptionHtml()
```

Comment: yes, custom options i see, but if custom options - radiobutton or checkbox, how get custom options - radiobutton or checkbox options (clickable for choose options =))?

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your question? Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: i need get all custom options from product, and then display in page template for future use

Comment: Added update to the answer.